# C++ Function always returns the same pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a function searching a node from the binary tree and return a Node pointer pointing to the found node like this:

```
template <class T>
Node<T>* BST<T>::findNode(T a,Node<T>* node)
{
  cout<<node->value<<endl;
  if(a == node->value)
  {
    return node;
  }
  if(a < node->value)
  {
    if(node->left==NULL)
    {
      return NULL;
    }
    findNode(a, node->left);
  }
  if(a > node->value)
  {
    if(node->right==NULL)
    {
      return NULL;
    }
    findNode(a, node->right);
  }
}
```

In the main program, I have a pointer （called bst）pointing to an instance of Binary Search Tree which is populated with some nodes. And I declared a Node pointer and called the function like this:

```
    Node <int> * n = bst-> findNode(3,bst->head);
```

**The problem:** The function works well if it can't find the matching value, however, if it does find the matching value (i.e. go the the `if(a==node->value) block`, it will always return the same value (in my computer, the Node n  always get the value of 0x6), how it happened and how to fix that?

TIA!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your recursive calls are not actually returning the node: they need to look like

```
return findNode(a, node->left);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function has return statement only for the condition

```
if(a == node->value)
{
    return node;
}
```

or for conditions like this

```
if(node->left==NULL)
{
  return NULL;
}
```

In all other cases the function has undefined behaviour.

Also this statement in the beginning of the function

```
cout<<node->value<<endl;
```

as well as the condition shown above are wrong because in general `node` can be equal to `nullptr`.

I would write the function the following way

```
template <class T>
Node<T>* BST<T>::findNode( Node<T> *node, const T &value )
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    if ( node == nullptr || node->value == value )
    {
        return node;
    }
    else if ( node->value < value )
    {
        return findNode( node->right, value );
    }
    else
    {
        return findNode( node->left, value );
    }
}
```